# why could not import the Result class from dart async

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to import the Result from dart async, but after I import the dart async, the Result still could not be found. This is my classs:

```
import 'package:reddwarf_dict/models/login/cellphone_existence_check.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class LoginApi {
  static Future<Result<CellphoneExistenceCheck>> checkPhoneExist(
      String phone, String countryCode) async {
    return Result.value(null);
  }
}
```

this is the message that tell me could not import the `Result`:

```
The name 'Result' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
```

what should I to to import the `Result` success? The Dart environment SDK like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [async package](https://pub.dev/packages/async) to your Flutter project: `flutter pub add async`

Or with dart:
`dart pub add async`

And in your code you need this import:

`import 'package:async/async.dart';`